# uploading to S3 using php and updating the database

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket, and am using a GitHub [S3 class](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class), and I am successful in uploading a file, yet I haven't understood how can I update my database with the file path and name, once I have uploaded it.

Any help on the issue will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** code from GitHub which handles the upload

```
<?php
/**
* $Id$
*
* S3 form upload example
*/

if (!class_exists('S3')) require_once 'S3.php';

// AWS access info
if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'AccessKey');
if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'SecretKey');

// Check for CURL
if (!extension_loaded('curl') && !@dl(PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX == 'so' ? 'curl.so' : 'php_curl.dll'))
    exit("\nERROR: CURL extension not loaded\n\n");

// Pointless without your keys!
if (awsAccessKey == 'change-this' || awsSecretKey == 'change-this')
    exit("\nERROR: AWS access information required\n\nPlease edit the following lines in this file:\n\n".
    "define('awsAccessKey', 'change-me');\ndefine('awsSecretKey', 'change-me');\n\n");


S3::setAuth(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

$bucket = 'media-socialbeautyapp-com';
$path = ''; // Can be empty ''

$lifetime = 3600; // Period for which the parameters are valid
$maxFileSize = (1024 * 1024 * 50); // 50 MB

$metaHeaders = array('uid' => 123);
$requestHeaders = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=${filename}'
);

$params = S3::getHttpUploadPostParams(
    $bucket,
    $path,
    S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
    $lifetime,
    $maxFileSize,
    201, // Or a URL to redirect to on success
    $metaHeaders,
    $requestHeaders,
    false // False since we're not using flash
);

$uploadURL = 'https://' . $bucket . '.s3.amazonaws.com/';

?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>S3 Form Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $uploadURL; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
    foreach ($params as $p => $v)
        echo "        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{$p}\" value=\"{$v}\" />\n";
?>
        <input type="file" name="file" />&#160;<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    <img src="https://media-socialbeautyapp-com.s3.amazonaws.com/Untitled-1.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

this code is from GitHub and it's ok yo upload files, but I don't know how to make it also update a database server I have.

Comment: Can you show us some of your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this very helpful, one upload, works flawlessly.

[S3 Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease/)

Answer (score 1):

Add another hidden input field with name="success_action_redirect". The value is the callback URL on your server. You can attach parameters to the callback URL, S3 will call it on success. Don't forget to generate a token and passing that along to make sure it is your callback coming back.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is uploading directly to S3, so you really don't have a way to know what was uploaded.

Consider [uploading the file to your local server **first**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), write to the DB and then upload to S3.

Read up on [`inputFile()`](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#inputFile) method - that looks like something you can use to upload files on your local disk to S3.

Comment: Uploading to the server first is ridiculous. Just use success_action_redirect to get a callback after the s3 post is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar thing at the moment. I'm temporarily uploading it to my server, writing to the DB, and then pushing it to S3. However, this is effectively TWO uploads, and therefore takes twice as long.

Ideally you'd like to add some of your own inputs and have amazon re-direct back to your site with the POST variables still intact. Amazon won't let you do that however. So it requires something a bit cleverer.

I haven't worked it out yet though, maybe something with AJAX